# Cannot connect to second router wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

I am trying to set up two routers on my network (secondary to be VPN router).  I have the secondary router at 192.168.2.1 and the primary at 192.168.1.1.

I've disabled DHCP from the secondary router and am running it in 'wireless router' mode.

My wired computer connected to the secondary router has internet, but I am unable to connect any device to the second router via WIFI.  I'm assuming something is going wrong with obtaining IPs, but am not sure.

Here is a diagram of my network layout:

[image: diagram]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to provide a diagram of your set up?

Comment: Diagram: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/xvFoneK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Also your subnet 192.168.2.1/24 needs a DHCP server unless you plan to use static IP on all connected devices on the lan side of it. Why lan ports take you to internet and not Wifi can be explained by that PC actually has static ip. This is the first things to fix.

Comment: I thought only one router could have DHCP enabled?  I enabled it on the secondary router and now both routers offer WIFI with internet..  Thanks!

Comment: That is not correct even if your Wifi's were in the same subnet. Nothing can go bad just because two can deliver IPs. In your case it is easier because the Wifi behind VPN is in it's own subnet, thus, devices cannot see any DHCP. DHCP doesn't traverse subnets without some advanced router hacking.